# Popping backstack throws "Fragment Already Added" exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I've been trying to solve the strangest problem concerning backstack management.

The goal is to have the following logic (fragments are represented by letters A,B,C):

A -> B,  B -> C , and when backPressed, C -> A

since C can be different fragments and, when in C and backPressed, fragment B should never appear, I add the transition A->B to backstack and B->C is not added, simply replaced B with C, so when I do backPress, C goes to A.

This works perfectly on the first time - the behavior is as expected, but when I try it the second time in a row, the app crashes in:

`getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()`

, throwing the exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: FragmentC`
...

I've tried replacing with `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack`, but simply the error is thrown some nanoseconds later.

Is there any reason why, while trying to pop the fragment from stack, an error of adding it is being thrown? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: have you add or update fragment? if you will add every time then will happen

Comment: show some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not throwing the exception due to the back stack popping, it's throwing it due to (A) being already attached. Ensure that you are using remove or replace when going to B and C to prevent A from being in an added/attached state.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to tell exactly what the problem is but I've a fair idea. The fragment backstack just stores FragmentTransactions, not actual fragments. And when it's popped when you click back, it simply reverses this transaction as it got it. So in your case you first go forward with a replace transaction or whatever [Remove A -> Add B] and add to the backstack. Then you go B->C and don't add that to the backstack. So the backstack is now still [Add A -> Remove B]. Remember the backstack is just the reversed forward transaction. Now you're on C which the backstack doesn't know about and click back and Android executes the backstack. It adds A and tries to remove B, but B isn't there so nothing happens. So now you're back on the A fragment with the C fragment underneath it which you probably don't know about. You can confirm this C fragment is behind in the debugger.

Now you said it crashes the second time you click back. So you're back on A with the C fragment underneath it and you're going from A->B and adding to the backstack. You're probably using [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace_2) which removes ALL added fragments and adds the new one. So the transaction is [Remove A, Remove C which is underneath, Add B] and adding that to the backstack. Now you go from B->C and this is the bit I can't be sure about without seeing your code. You're getting a `Fragment already added` error which means you must be getting the same C instance somewhere when going from B->C. Are you using some `findFragmentByTag` in your replace?

So you've the same C fragment instance from the first time loaded and visible and you click back. Android tries to reverse the previous transaction and tries to Add A which works, then Add C which is the same fragment instance as currently visible and you get your `Fragment already added` error.